# Pass object in service

Tags: php, oop, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
# Sonata\MediaBundle/Resources/config/admin.yml
services:
    sonata.admin.post:
        class: Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\MediaAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "Post" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
            - ~
            - Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\Pool //??????????????
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [Sonata\MediaBundle]]
```

If this service is executed then i have error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 4 passed to Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\BaseMediaAdmin::__construct() must be an instance of Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\Pool, none given, called in C:\server\fs\app\cache\dev\appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 1535 and defined in C:\server\fs\vendor\bundles\Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\BaseMediaAdmin.php line 34
```

because 4 argument is string instead of object.

```
/**
 * @param string                            $code
 * @param string                            $class
 * @param string                            $baseControllerName
 * @param \Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\Pool $pool
 */
public function __construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName, Pool $pool)
{
    parent::__construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName);

    $this->pool = $pool;
}
```

How can i pass object with this service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You inject class name instead service. Try inject `sonata.media.pool` service as 4th constructor argument:

```
services:
    sonata.admin.post:
        class: Sonata\MediaBundle\Admin\MediaAdmin
        tags:
            - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, group: "Content", label: "Post" }
        arguments:
            - ~
            - Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media
            - ~
            - @sonata.media.pool
        calls:
            - [ setTranslationDomain, [Sonata\MediaBundle]]
```

Comment: thanks, but why sonata.media.pool and not sonata.media.provider.pool etc?

Comment: Please look at bundle `provider.xml` code: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/provider.xml#L21